# How to remove App for Office from Office 365

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook, office365, office-app

I created an App for Office 365 using visual studio. I tested the app and worked out how it works etc. Now I want to remove it from my outlook 365 and I cant find out how to do it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Log into outlook.com
2. Click on the gear on the top right
3. Click manage apps
4. Find the app you created in the list
5. Delete it with the minues (-) button